# Window reloads before alert is displayed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've resolved my issue but I could not understand the logic...

Before reloading my parent page on submit from an iframe I wanted to `alert("something");`
my code was like:

```
alert("something");

window.parent.location.reload();
```

But the alert was not displayed at all and the page was reloaded.

```
if(!alert("something"))

window.parent.location.reload();
```

This mandated the alert but y want is it displayed earlier?

Comment: Alert boxes are modal. The `if` statement should not be necessary. Maybe there is an asynchronous routine that also reloads the page, can you post more of your code?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: not necessarily, but AFAIK all browsers implement them as modal dialogs.

Comment: @Quantas, after re-reading the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#user-prompts), it appears you're right: `prompt()` and `confirm()` must display modal dialogs, but that's optional for `alert()`.